# Erro 501 ao conectar com FTP

Tags: c#, winforms, ftp

Eu tenho uma aplicação C# (Windows Forms) que acessa o FTP da empresa para baixar alguns arquivos e/ou fazer upload.

Só que, em dois clientes específicos, o aplicativo não consegue acessar o FTP. Ele dá o seguinte erro:

> O servidor remoto retornou um erro: (501) Erro de sintaxe em parâmetros ou argumentos.

Eu tenho procurado exaustivamente sobre este erro, mas não tem nada de significante.

O que pode ser?

Meu código

```
string enderecoUltimaVersao = "ftp://meusite.com.br/releases/ultima";

FtpWebRequest request = FtpWebRequest.Create(enderecoUltimaVersao) as FtpWebRequest;
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, senha);
request.UsePassive = true;
request.UseBinary = true;
request.KeepAlive = false;

FtpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as FtpWebResponse;
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    string file = reader.ReadLine();
    files.Add(file);
}
```

Comment: Poderia ser algo a ver com o Firewall/Proxy destas redes que está causando o Erro 501?

Comment: Como você está fazendo para abrir a conexão? Tem um exemplo em código?

Comment: @Tony, eles não têm proxy e, no firewall do Windows, eu liberei normal, como faço nos outros.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, vou fazer um EDIT

Comment: Qual o formato de `enderecoUltimaVersao`?

Comment: Adiciona à pergunta o conteúdo de "enderecoUltimaVersao".

Comment: É o endereco "ftp: //meusite.com.br/pasta/versao", @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Comment: Eu não entendi esta linha `string file = reader.ReadLine();false);` o que significa este `false)`?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento foi uma linha que eu apaguei pela metade, já corrigi na questão.